# Bootstrap 3 carousel for mobile and normal grid for web

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Can anyone please help me how can I achieve this. I want to show 2 rows each with 3 grids in desktop version, the same page if I open it in mobile instead of showing one below the other I want to give bootstrap carousel effect for it. I have attached png file for both mobile and web.
[image: web version view]

[image: Mobile version view]

Comment: Something like this?
https://jsfiddle.net/jo9j9z8a/

Answer (score 2):

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/obna7dvw/)**

Create a `carousel` as below. Add each `columns` you have in desktop view inside `item` of the carousel

```
//hide it in desktop view and tablet view and show it in mobile view
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide hidden-md hidden-sm col-xs-12" data-ride="carousel">

  <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
  <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
    <div class="item active"> //put all your row items in each `item` here
          Item One
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      Item One
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      Item Two
    </div>


  </div>

  <!-- Left and right controls -->
  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">

    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>
```

Add your normal code with a class attached to parent to hide it in mobile view as below:

```
<div class="container col-md-12 hidden-xs"> //Parent to be hidden in mobile
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            Item One
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            Item Two
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            Item Three
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

---

**UPDATE**

So to do this dynamically you can create a dynamic carousel based on whether the user is browsing through `mobile device` or not and below is the code:

```
if( /Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent) ) {
    var itemsToWrap=$('.testItem');
    $('.parentTest').remove();
    var carousel='<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide hidden-md hidden-sm col-xs-12" data-ride="carousel"><div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox"></div>  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>  </a>  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>  </a></div>';
    $(carousel).appendTo('.baseParent');
    var elementTowrap="";
    $.each($(itemsToWrap),function(index){
        var html=$(this).html();
        console.log(html);
        if(index==0)
            elementTowrap+='<div class="item active">'+$(this).html()+'</div>';
        else
            elementTowrap+='<div class="item">'+$(this).html()+'</div>';
    });
    $('.carousel-inner').append($(elementTowrap));
    $("#myCarousel").carousel("pause").removeData();
    $("#myCarousel").carousel();
}
```

**[DEMO HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/7nse91m9/1/)**

**For Demo purpose I have used `$(window).width()` to show how it works as you cannot test whether it is mobile or not in `browser`**

> **NOTE** - I have made some changes to your `html` as well! Kindly note it!

Comment: Thanks Guruprasad for your answer. I m doing the same thing now. But I was thinking will there be any way without repeating the code i can achieve the same.

Comment: Well you can use `jquery` to do this! Identify whether the user is browsing in mobile on `document.ready`. If yes take each `item` and create a bootstrap `carousel` structure and wrap each item inside `item` of carousel!! If you create a `demo` with current `html` code I can help you!!

Comment: No no!! I asked the html structure of what you have right now!! The one you showed in images in question!

Comment: @ChandrikaDesai Updated answer!! Check and let me know!!

Comment: @ Guruprasad i m looking at jsfiddle link, nothing updated in the link. Can u plz help me out with your updated fiddle? Thanks!

Comment: Ok. See this **[FULL SCREEN RESULT](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/7nse91m9/1/embedded/result/)** and  try resizing it!! You will find the changes

Comment: @Is that what you were expecting?

Comment: This strategy could have undesirable SEO implications, the proper solution will not duplicate content to hide/show it on desktop/mobile.